# Inherit constructors from template base class without repeating template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, constructor

How do I inherit constructors from a template base class without repeating the template arguments (and without using macros):

For example, this does not work (using GCC 4.8):

```
template <typename T>
struct base {};

template <typename U>
struct derived : base<U> {
    using base::base;
};
```

It does work if I repeat the template arguments of the base class:

```
template <typename T>
struct base {};

template <typename U>
struct derived : base<U> {
    using base<U>::base;
};
```

The problem is that "U" might be something very complex and that is annoying and error prone to repeat. For example, here is one of my original motivating examples:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct as_list_tag {};
struct as_set_tag  {};

template <typename T>
struct unique_list : multi_index_container <
    T,
    indexed_by <
        sequenced<tag<as_list_tag>>,
        ordered_unique<tag<as_set_tag>, identity<T>>
    >
> {
    using multi_index_container <
        T,
        indexed_by <
            sequenced<tag<as_list_tag>>,
            ordered_unique<tag<as_set_tag>, identity<T>>
        >
    >
    ::multi_index_container;
    using as_list = as_list_tag;
    using as_set  = as_set_tag ;
};
```

I ended up working around this by using a macro:

```
#define MAKE_UNIQUE_LIST(template_params...)\
template <typename T>\
struct unique_list : multi_index_container template_params\
{\
    using multi_index_container template_params ::multi_index_container;\
    using as_list = as_list_tag;\
    using as_set  = as_set_tag ;\
};

MAKE_UNIQUE_LIST(<
    T,
    indexed_by <
        sequenced<tag<as_list_tag>>,
        ordered_unique<tag<as_set_tag>, identity<T>>
    >
>)
#undef MAKE_UNIQUE_LIST
```

Is there a better way to approach this? Some syntax trick I am missing? =)

Comment: `typedef base<U> parent;`

Comment: @MooingDuck You still have to repeat it at least twice (once in deriving and once in `using` to inherit constructors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't perfect, but you could have a class that generates your type:

```
template <typename T>
struct unique_list_base {
    typedef multi_index_container <
        T,
        indexed_by <
            sequenced<tag<as_list_tag>>,
            ordered_unique<tag<as_set_tag>, identity<T>>
        >
    > type;
};

template <typename T>
struct unique_list : unique_list_base<T>::type {
    using unique_list_base<T>::type::multi_index_container;
    using as_list = as_list_tag;
    using as_set  = as_set_tag ;
};
```

Comment: About the typename before the unique_list_base<T>::type GCC says: `keyword ‘typename’ not allowed in this context (the base class is implicitly a type)`

Comment: After removing the extra typename and fixing I typo where I was confusing myself, I was able to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: @wjl You can simplify it further by using `template<typename T> using unique_list_base = multi_index_container<...>;`.

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
template <typename U, typename thebase=base<U>>
struct derived : thebase {
    using thebase::thebase;
};
```

The downside is that it changes the external interface of the template to have two template arguments. You can solve that like this:

```
template <typename U, typename thebase=base<U>>
struct derived_impl : thebase {
    using thebase::thebase;
};
template<typename U>
using derived = derived_impl<U>;
```

Comment: Smart, but unfortunately does not work if U is a template parameter pack.

Answer (score 2):

Just to highlight Daniel Frey solution since he did not bothered to make a full answer: template using declaration (aka template typedef) is the way to go.

```
template <typename T>
using unique_list_base =
    multi_index_container <
        T,
        indexed_by <
            sequenced<tag<as_list_tag>>,
            ordered_unique<tag<as_set_tag>, identity<T>>
        >
    >;

template <typename T>
struct unique_list : unique_list_base<T> {
    using unique_list_base<T>::multi_index_container;
    using as_list = as_list_tag;
    using as_set  = as_set_tag ;
};
```

This way, you can get rid of the `struct` and all the associated boilerplate that were widely used with the C++03 `foobar<T>::type` idiom.

Comment: Nice. I've been using `using` a lot lately and I see it's useful yet again here! =)

Comment: Even better, this lets me change the inherited constructor line to `using unique_list_base<T>::unique_list_base;` which is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it appears that MSVC, as opposed to gcc, does not even require repeating the template argument: one could just write "using base::base".